# Aegir hostmaster custom profile

Tags: aegir, installation-profiles

I created a custom profile with a custom theme for Aegir. I would like to enable that theme by default when a user install hostmaster during the Aegir installation. In the Aegir installation hostmaster is installed when the user runs the below drush command

drush hostmaster-install

I would like to know is there any way to modify this command or any other way to set my custom profile as defautt one during the Aegir install process.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `hostmaster-install` command has options for `--profile` and `--makefile`.

I use these options for OpenDevShop, which has it's own makefile and profile.

You can use a URL or a path for makefile option.

```
    drush hostmaster-install --makefile=/path/to/mymake.make --profile=mycustomprofile
```

Answer (score 0):

It's done in hostmaster.install: `theme_enable(array('eldir'));`

You could patch that or better create a mini module of your own to later enable your own theme.